# How to Move Objects Precisely in Axes Other Than X,Y, and Z?

Tags: modeling

I am a beginner in Blender, so far I have googled the question I asked in the caption of this post, and haven't been able to find an answer for it.

Using G and moving it in X Y Z, or using middle mouse and moving objects in the aforementioned directions are so easy. But imagine if you want to move objects precisely in let's say, between X, and Y axes?

It is very irritating for me to only be able to move objects in direction of X, Y, and Z. I know I can go to top view and move them in any direction I want. But I would like to move them accurately. Last time I made a turbine and rotated it. The turbine blade had an animation and it was rotating on X axis, but as soon as I turned the turbine to direction between X, and Y, its blade went haywire, and rotated in a messed up manner, like it was loose or something.

I would like to know if there is any shortcut or hotkey to move objects in various directions precisely?

If not, how professionals move the objects accurately in any direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you can just G and move an object freely.

You can also hit G shift Z and move an object freely on its XY plane.  Same for shift X, shift Y.

You can also change the orientation that you're using, from Global to Local, or Normal, or View (or some others.)

You can also create a custom orientation from another object or face by selecting it and using "Create orientation" operation (ctrl alt space for me.)

You can also parent things (which would be useful for your turbine, likely) so that you can move or rotate the parent in its local axes, rather than those of the child.

You can even hit G X X to move only on the local x-axis of your object. Same for Y and Z.

Same for G shift Z shift Z -> moves only on local xy-plane.